# Motivation behind certain integrating factor

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this article](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/differential-equations/first-order-equations/integrating-factors) about exact differential equations, for the fourth example, they have the differential equation:

$$ (5xy^2 - 2y) dx  + (3xy^2 -x) dy = 0$$

And they say they integrating factor for this is $$ \mu(x,y) = x^a y^b$$

Now, I don't get how they arrived that this should be correct integrating factors for the problem. Of course, this does integrating factor does satisfy the requirement that the second-order partials commute but I can't really understand how I'd come up with this if it was not already told that this is the integrating factor.

If not, for what kinds of differential equations would this integrating factor work?

---

[Similar post to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547454/common-integrating-factor-of-two-differential-equations)

I have seen this post already and it is not the same as mine because the question was not really regarding the integrating factor which I mentioned but rather alternative methods.

Answer (score 2):

$$(5xy^2 - 2y) dx  + (\color{red}{3xy^2 }-x) dy = 0$$
You made a little mistake the correct differential equation is:
$$(5xy^2 - 2y) dx  + (3x^2y -x) dy = 0$$
Multiply by $x$:
$$(5x^2y^2 - 2yx) dx  + (3x^3y -x^2) dy = 0$$
Rearrange some terms:
$$(5x^2y^2dx   + 3x^3ydy)-(ydx^2 +x^2 dy) = 0$$
$$(5x^2y^2dx   + 3x^3ydy)-d(x^2y) = 0$$

The integrating factor is now obvious:
$$\mu(x,y)=x^2y$$
$$(5x^4y^3dx   + 3x^5y^2dy)-x^2yd(x^2y) = 0$$
$$d(x^5y^3)-x^2yd(x^2y) = 0$$
Then integrate:
$$2x^5y^3-x^4y^2 = C$$

Comment: I don't understand the step after you introduced the integrating factor. Why is the second equation just "the preceding one multiplied by $\mu$"?

Comment: Differentiate $x^5y^3$ and see what you get @ian Have i made a mistake Ian ?

Comment: I am not sure because I am not really sure what you were trying to do. But it doesn't look like you multiplied through by $\mu$ to get the fourth equation from the bottom, since $d(x^2 y)$ didn't get changed at all.

Comment: Let me add some details @ian

Comment: Oh I see now thanks corrected @Ian

Comment: Yes that makes more sense. +1.

Comment: Thank you  @ian ...

Comment: IF you could explain the thought process behind each step that you have made it would be easier to understand. For example, you suddenly multiplied by $x$ and then rearranged in the successive steps, how did you know that was what you had to do?

Comment: First I had already in minf to rearrange the terms and I know that $2xdx=dx^2$. So I wanted to have an exact differential with these two terms. I observed that multiplying by x will do the job.... Then after that I focused on the integrating factor and it was easy to deduce it from the differential equation ...@Buraian

Comment: Ok that makes sense but still doesn't explain why the integrating factor I put in the question is the general one for these kinds of problems

Comment: @Buraian These DE are really particular. They can be integrated with the kind of integrating factor you are given.

Comment: I don't completely agree there are a lot of questions which I have seen of the form P(x) dx + Q(x) dy = 0, where P and Q are polynomials, the integrating factor is one I have written. I'm trying to figure out a reason why this integrating factor is the one

Comment: $P(x) dx + Q(x) dy = 0,$ dosent require any integrating factor @Buraian

Comment: my bad, it is P(x,y) and Q(x,y)

Comment: I see what you mean. @Buraian

Answer (score 0):

If for $(5xy^2-2y)~dx+(3xy^2-x)~dy=0$ , we should need another approach:

$(5xy^2-2y)~dx+(3xy^2-x)~dy=0$

$\dfrac{dx}{dy}=-\dfrac{3xy^2-x}{5xy^2-2y}$

Let $x=yu$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dx}{dy}=y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u$

$\therefore y\dfrac{du}{dy}+u=-\dfrac{3y^3u-yu}{5y^3u-2y}$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{3y^3u-yu}{5y^3u-2y}-u$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{5y^3u^2+3y^3u-3yu}{5y^3u-2y}$

$y\dfrac{du}{dy}=-\dfrac{5y^2u^2+3y^2u-3u}{5y^2u-2}$

Let $r=y^2$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{dy}=\dfrac{du}{dr}\dfrac{dr}{dy}=2y\dfrac{du}{dr}$

$\therefore2y^2\dfrac{du}{dr}=-\dfrac{5y^2u^2+3y^2u-3u}{5y^2u-2}$

$2r\dfrac{du}{dr}=-\dfrac{5ru^2+3ru-3u}{5ru-2}$

$(2-5ru)\dfrac{du}{dr}=\dfrac{5u^2}{2}+\dfrac{3(r-1)u}{2r}$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.